# Uploaded binary Picture into database and display in listview

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am try to uploaded an image to a database which work but I can't display the image in a ListView which has a sql datasource

This is my upload image code

```
int img = ImageUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

byte[] msdata = new byte[img];

ImageUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(msdata, 0, img);

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_1", msdata);
```

display image

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "image_1") %>'  CssClass="background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,IVB)" />
```

This is the error I keep getting

> Unable to translate Unicode character \uDAFF at index 15 to specified code page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go my way immediately, but I tried it, and worked quite quickly:

I created a method that returns a File object to the browser:

```
public ActionResult GetThumbnail(Guid id)
{
    var fileToRetrieve = Db.Pictures.Find(id);

    if (fileToRetrieve == null)
        return null;

    if (fileToRetrieve.Thumbnail == null)
        return null;

    return File(fileToRetrieve.Thumbnail, fileToRetrieve.ContentType);
}
```

In the browser, I just set the img src attribute to that method with the ID I need to retrieve.

```
<img src="~/Picture/GetThumbnail?id=@item.Id" />
```